# How many people would it take to colonize Mars?

Tags: space-colonization, planets, population

To ensure a self-sufficient colony, there would need to be enough people to ensure a diverse gene pool, a wide variety of technical experience, and enough bodies to work farms and such. How many people would be necessary for such an undertaking?

Comment: What are your starting condition for the colonization? As it is today not even the entire population of Earth could be enough to colonize it, as they would quickly be dead.

Comment: This question has been asked many times in many ways on this site.  The **Questions that may already have your answer** section below the title field when you asked your question had most of them.  It is bad maners to ignore that list.